# Cross validation matlab - crossval function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, knn, cross-validation

I do not understand what the function "***crossval***" in matlab takes as first parameter, I understand that it is a function for performing a regression, but I don´t get what is intended as "***some criterion testval***". I need to use it on a K-nn regressor, but the examples are not making everything clear to me.

```
vals = crossval(fun,X)
```

> Each time it is called, fun should use XTRAIN to fit a model, then
>   return some criterion testval computed on XTEST using that fitted
>   model.

Here is where I am reading: [Matlab reference](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/crossval.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be similar to optimization functions, where the returned value from your fitting function `fun` should be an indication of how well it fits the data. As [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) states, `fun` takes two arguments, a training data set `XTRAIN` and a testing data set `XTEST`.

If your data, `X`, comprises a column of known results `X(:,1)` and other columns of features `X(:, 2:end)`, and train your data using `XTRAIN`, then your return value could be as simple as the sum-squared error of the fitted model:

```
testval = sum( (model(XTEST(:, 2:end)) - XTEST(:, 1)).^2 );
```

where `model(XTEST(:, 2:end))` is the result of your fitted model on the features of the testing data set, XTEST, and `XTEST(:, 1)` are the known results for those feature sets.